# LSTM Plotting Actual vs Predicted in Python Shape Error

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, lstm

I am trying to plot LSTM results of actual vs prediction and I am getting this error

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (14,) and (1, 2)
```

I get what it means but I am uncertain how to fix it. This is my code below:

```
aa=[x for x in range(14)]
plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
plt.plot(aa, Y_test[0][:200], marker='.', label="actual")
plt.plot(aa, test_predict[:,0][:152], 'r', label="prediction")
# plt.tick_params(left=False, labelleft=True) #remove ticks
plt.tight_layout()
sns.despine(top=True)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.07)
plt.ylabel('Global_active_power', size=15)
plt.xlabel('Time step', size=15)
plt.legend(fontsize=15)
plt.show();
```

Comment: As the error message said, your `aa` and `Y_test[0][:200]` or `test_predict[:,0][:152]` have different shape. To fix, you can print the value of `Y_test[0][:200]` to see what it looks like.

Comment: Hello @jasonwong.  Thanks so when I print(Y_test[0][:200]) I get [6515.9994738  5244.99993883].  When I print print(test_predict[:,0][:152]) I get [2447.6116 2284.4739] so how do I fix this?  I understand that the shapes don't match but how do I correctly put in the right shapes?